# Azure DevOps get File(s) update from Pull Request using Rest-API

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

In Azure DevOps Pull request has a Files tab, where its possible to get the diff of the different updates happen to the pull request.

[image]

or

[image]

It shows the diff of the file(s) and the respective content.

How does this happen? Which (or if any exist) in Azure DevOps Rest-API does return for such query?
I've checked and tested the offered Rest-Api from Microsoft,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2

and was expecting that something like this(or Pull-Requests) would do it,

GET `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits/{commitId}/changes?api-version=7.1`

But it doesn't and also it don't have option to compare between.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shared is the changeset from the Pull request change dropdown list. For each changeset, you can use rest api [Pull Request Iterations - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-iterations/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0) to get the changeset details.

For example: update 3- update 4, it's `iteration 4`. Update2-udapte 3, it's `iteration 3`, you can also find the iteration id from browser:

[image]

In rest api response, it contains the **commit id** for this changeset.
[image]

Or directly use rest api [Pull Request Commits - Get Pull Request Iteration Commits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-commits/get-pull-request-iteration-commits?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0) (with top=1 parameter) to get the commit id for iteration:
[image]

With commit id, you can get the change details with rest api [Commits - Get Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-changes?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) or git command `git show commitid`.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi @meAbab, may i know if it helps? let me know if you have any queries.